# SQL union select multiple colomns

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to select both the score and user_id from two identical tables (execpt from their table names)

```
SELECT user_id, score as score
    FROM (
        SELECT tes.score FROM test_score tes INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = tes.user_id WHERE U.organization_id = 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tas.score FROM task_score tas INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = tas.user_id WHERE U.organization_id = 7
    ) AS subquery ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

however when i run this i get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'
```

The table look like this:

```
Table: test_score
Columns:
id  int(11) PK AI
user_id int(11) 
module_id   int(11) 
score   double 
number_correct  int(11) 
correct_total   int(11) 
timestamp   datetime 
phase_id    int(11) 
medal_id    int(11) 
team_id int(11) 
status_id   int(11)
```

Comment: `user_id` is not selected in the inner query, the outer query has no idea what it is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner query doesn't return any columns called `user_id`, so it's not possible for the outer query to access it.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT user_id, score as score
    FROM (
        SELECT tes.user_id, tes.score FROM test_score tes INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = tes.user_id WHERE U.organization_id = 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tas.user_id, tas.score FROM task_score tas INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = tas.user_id WHERE U.organization_id = 7
    ) AS subquery ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to select user_id in the subquery in both SELECT statements.

```
SELECT user_id, score as score
    FROM (
        SELECT tes.user_id, tes.score FROM test_score tes INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = tes.user_id WHERE U.organization_id = 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tas.user_id, tas.score FROM task_score tas INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = tas.user_id WHERE U.organization_id = 7
    ) AS subquery ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```